# MySQL Case update not working in PHP, working within MySQL though

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE languages
               SET val = CASE id
                                  WHEN '1' THEN '$PageIsLoading'
                                  WHEN '2' THEN '$start'
                                  WHEN '3' THEN '$DM'
                                  WHEN '4' THEN '$experience'
                                  ...
                                  WHEN '25' THEN '$mate'
                                  WHEN '26' THEN '$gloss'
                                  WHEN '27' THEN '$uvLaquer'
                                  WHEN '28' THEN '$without'
                                  WHEN '29' THEN '$oneFace'
                                  WHEN '30' THEN '$twoFace'
                                  WHEN '31' THEN '$Quantity'
                                  WHEN '32' THEN '$BeginProject'
                                  WHEN '33' THEN '$ImportantNote'
                                  WHEN '34' THEN '$FinalPrice'
                                  WHEN '35' THEN '$coords' 
                                  ELSE val
                                  END
             WHERE `id` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35');
```

If I pass it through MySQL alone (for example execute it using HeidiSQL) it will update the cells with new values.
When I pass it through PHP though, it won't do anything at all. 
The variables in the script are specified and, if I echo them, they appear as they should be. Also, they are stripped from any problematic chars using `htmlentities()`.
In the PHP script I use the following:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "THEQUERY");
```

Even if I put the variables like `"QUERY STUFF ".$var." QUERY STUFF "` it doesn't change anything...
Completely out of ideas as I used the same kind of query various times in the project and always worked!

Comment: what does `echo $THE_QUERY` shows?

Comment: it shows the query as it should be with the variables properly echoed, if it execute it from HeidiSQL it works perfectly.
PS: Just tested another query to check if the 
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "THEQUERY");
chunk works right, and it does. So, again, PHP just won't execut the sql for some reason...

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try `echo mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bbold'>Gestão de Resíduos com certificado APIGRAF, ao abrigo de um ' at line 11
Strange, as I sanitize every variabe and I shouldn't have problems with quotes as they are html entities now...

Comment: I guess I could do all 35 updates separately, but that'd be too much queries at once... Not sure..

Comment: `$str = "bla'bla"; THEN '$str'` will fail (as `THEN 'bla'bla'`) because of quotation, you should escape quotes here

Comment: even if they're not acutal quotes but html entities?

Comment: htmlentities does not force quotes to be transformed except it's said explicitly. You can try `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: Yes, that fixed it finally... (But I've lost the encoding...)

Comment: You can specify both encoding and quote type

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con, 'THEQUERY');
```

ie replace double quotes to single (" to '). Because if use " php will try to parse and replace variables (starting with $).

Comment: This is not relevant.